# Can I view the id/version number of the schema that is being sent to Kafka? for debugging purpose

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I want to view the Id/version of the schema to be referred in a record while publishing data from producer.

If I have 3 versions of schemas and I'm publishing data for the version 1.
Can I see the version number before sending the record to kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to get the schema version number, only the global schema ID (via an HTTP POST to /subjects/:name)

You would have to scan all /versions of the subject and compare your schema against those.

Or you can try looking at the logs of the registry / enable trace logging on the registry client in the producer

Comment: Yes after scanning, How can I know which version of the schema is actually sent?

Comment: By using `.equals` method of the Schema class, then getting the version of the HTTP json response. Can you explain your use case for needing the version in the producer code?

Comment: It is for learning purpose, I was playing around the compatibility to know more on them.